# Internet Explorer posting form into iframe under security. Random results

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, post, iframe

Using IE8, I found this weird issue: when I press on the submit button below, sometimes IE posts the data on the inputs and sometimes it doesn't.

It doesn't matter if the browser is on Compatibility View or not.

I have been looking extensively for a solution to this issue because is driving me mad. I have tried posting it in other ways (like using jQuery) with the same result.

The idea is that depending on some parameters, it would load one page or another inside the iframe.

It works absolutely fine on other browsers like FF or Chrome. It also works on IE9.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="123.php" target="my_iframe">
            <input name="stu[0][All]">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <iframe  name="my_iframe" src="about:blank" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the target (123.php) it just shows the $_POST. This page is protected by basic authentication.

123.php :

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, and can not find the solution.
I've watched in some posts, people saying that is the doctype, but already changed and does not work, you want to change the doctype and do a test?

this is my post:
[post-to-iframe-dont-work-in-internet-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127431/post-to-iframe-dont-work-in-internet-explorer#comment14584698_11127431)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue, and it had to do with Internet Explorer having problems posting to a page that requires basic authentication, and IE behaves in a random manner.

Solution is to unprotect the page or to use GET